# How to share the PHPmyadmin in LAN in Windows environment?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

This may be the serverfault question.
I am using XAMPP in my system.I want to access the PHPMyadmin from my network's another computer.How can I achieve this?

Update:

I want to access through my application also.So How can I connect in this

```
mysql_connect(path,'root','')
```

And also I have changed in Apache httpd.conf file like this

```
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter this in your other computer?

```
http://<IP of your computer (something like 192.168.0.100)>/phpmyadmin/
```

You can find out your IP by double-clicking on your network connection and looking at the second tab.

Edit: If you set the permissions correctly in MySQL, you can use

```
mysql_connect('<IP>','root','')
```

to connect.

Comment: I tried this.And also I added the user in phpmyadmin to access any host and password is NO.Its not work out.But It opens in the browser.

Comment: `If you set the permissions correctly in MySQL, you can use` How can I set the permissions correctly

Comment: Look here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html (you can skip step one)

Comment: Same thing: Look for `my.cnf` in the XAMPP Program folder (propably in a folder named `mysql`), edit the file like in step 3, close it, restart mysql (or the whole XAMPP if that's easier) and try it out.

Comment: When I search(my.cnf) the entire xampp I got the result in `xampp\mysql\bin` .But I dont know what the extension is.It simplt display my and also I dont know how to edit it.

Comment: Try notepad/editor. If notepad/editor displays strange characters and only one row, try Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

Comment: It does. Open editor/notepad/notepad++, click File->Open, select "All files" as filetype and open the file. What happens?

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer to the oposite problem, deny access in lan and inverted the procedure  to solve the same problem, it works for me. [answer oposite.](http://www.hellothupten.com/2013/11/24/block-access-to-phpmyadmin-from-lan-network-on-xampp/)

**EDIT**
Here are the steps:
First open httpd-xampp.conf, Usually  it's located in:
c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf
then at the bottom of the file change the default value:
Usually like this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

to this:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Lastly reestart apache.

I think that doing that we are allowing a range of local ip's to acces phpmyadmin through some kind of regex, you can find some more about it in the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html)

I hope this can be useful to someone with the same need to acces phpmyadmin in the lan.

Comment: You should describe the steps taken to solve the issue in your answer. Directing people to links is discouraged as they are subject to 'link rot'.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the httpd.conf file in the Apache and Give your IP address where ever you find either loccalhost or 127.0.0.1.

You can use the IP address of the host where DB exists

mysql_connect('ip_addr', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');